# Use Bootswatch with .net core web app (razor not MVC)

Tags: css, .net, razor, bootstrap-4, bootswatch

I'm trying to use a bootswatch theme with my .net core web app but I can't seem to find any guides.

I have tried replacing the bootstrap.css file with the bootstrap.css of my desired theme but it's not working.

I noticed the default bootstrap.css file has an associated bootstrap.css.map file because the default project is using LESS. How can I use these bootswatch themes with the default .net core web app project?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how i resolved it; first you visit the official site of bootswatch, you realize that the templates are always tuned to the lates version of boostrap; in my case it was tuned to v4.1.1 which is the latest version of bootstrap. 
[versioned tuned in the bootswatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rwYq.png)

now check your _Layout.cshtml page and see the bootstrap version included by asp.net core; mine was  v3.3.7. Back to your bootswatch select the correct version and enjoy coding. Hope this helps you